# Await a promise in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to await a promise before implementing another logic. For example i have a request (first) and second request (second). When i will make second request, inside it i want to await the first one and after that to add additional logic. For this i created:

```
 async function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then( json => {
        console.log('first'); 
      })
  }
  
  async function f1() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(async json => {
        await resolveAfter2Seconds();
        console.log('second'); 
      })
  }
  
   const click = () => {
    f1();
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={click}>click</button>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

So, when i click on the button i want to see in the console the firstly the text `first` and after that `second`. This is why i implemented this:

```
await resolveAfter2Seconds();
console.log('second');
```

The issue is that the code acts in this order: `second` and `first` . How to make the first request to occur first?

Comment: Neither `resolveAfter2Seconds` nor `f1` actually returns the `fetch`-created promise chain, so they both implicitly `return Promise.resolve(undefined)` (because they're `async` functions, which always returns promises) immediately after starting the request. Neither needs to be marked `async`, as neither `await`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your first function resolves instantly. What you have is

```
 async function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json()) // happens later, when the call is completed
      .then( json => {
        console.log('first'); 
      })
    return; // happens now
  }
```

Just add a return statement and things will happen in the right order

```
async function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then( // etc.
}
```

(BTW, if you're already using `async` functions, it would be probably better to get rid of the `then`s and convert them to `await` syntax).